# How to program a user-specific RSS reader that checks for new XML data every 15 minutes in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss

Basically I'm confused by how to implement a site where a user logs in and they are able to select a certain RSS feed and then my site/server will notify them by email when the RSS is updated (every 15 minutes or so) or based on keywords they provide. I understand how to parse XML, but not sure how I can have this function running individually for any user that signs up for this service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done outside of ASP.NET using a kind of scheduler. You can build your own solution using Windows Service/Timer or use 3rd party solution like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

At a very basic, every time scheduled interval elapses - you loop thru your user accounts, parse their RSS feeds and notify users about new items.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Once I set up my database I'm sure this should be an easy task to set up. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Please check as answered if suggestion was useful.